# Am I calling the JavaScript file correctly?

Tags: javascript

I have a web page and I was wondering if I am calling correctly `javascript3.js`. The file is inside the same folder as the html. When I put the javascript code inside the html, it works fine.

(The `ol3-layerswitcher.js` is being called correctly so I don't know why the other one is not being called.)

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
        <title>Map</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://openlayers.org/en/v3.12.1/css/ol.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="ol3-layerswitcher.css">
        <script src="http://openlayers.org/en/v3.12.1/build/ol.js"></script>
        <script src="ol3-layerswitcher.js"></script>
        <script src="javascript3.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map" style="width:100%;"></div>
    <div id="info"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

javascript3.js:

```
var testSource = new ol.source.TileWMS({
url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms',
params: {'LAYERS': 'Marine:Great_Britain', 'TILED': true},
    serverType: 'geoserver'
});

  var layers = [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.MapQuest({layer: 'osm'})
    }),

        new ol.layer.Group({
            title: 'Layers',
            layers: [

                //Implementing layers
                new ol.layer.Tile({
                    title: 'Great Britain',
                    source: testSource
                }),
            ]
        })


  ];
  var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: layers,
    target: 'map',
    view: new ol.View({
      center: [51480.6, 7216744.2], //UK
      zoom: 5
    })
  });

  //Function to get features from layer
  map.on('singleclick', function(evt) {
    document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = '';
    viewResolution = map.getView().getResolution();
    var url = testSource.getGetFeatureInfoUrl(
        evt.coordinate, viewResolution, 'EPSG:3857',
        {'INFO_FORMAT': 'text/html'});
    if (url) {
      document.getElementById('info').innerHTML =
          '<iframe seamless src="' + url + '"></iframe>';
    }
  });


  //Layer switcher to turn layers on and off
   var layerSwitcher = new ol.control.LayerSwitcher({
   tipLabel: 'Legend'
});
map.addControl(layerSwitcher);
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your console?

Comment: Hard to say for certain, but I'm going to bet that you are targeting the `div` with the id `map` before it's loaded. You can either put the code in `javascript3.js` inside an onload / document ready handler, or you can just move the `script` tag that loads `javascript3.js` to the bottom of your html page (you can leave the other two in `head`, probably)

Comment: yes, the question is: where did you put the JavaScript code inside the html when it worked? the same position? and: of course, check out the dev tools.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to execute DOM manipulation without wrapping your code into [document ready handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState) (such as [`$(document).ready();`](https://api.jquery.com/ready/)), the correct place is at the end of `body` (or at least after creating the DOM elements to be manipulated):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
        <title>Map</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://openlayers.org/en/v3.12.1/css/ol.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="ol3-layerswitcher.css">
        <script src="http://openlayers.org/en/v3.12.1/build/ol.js"></script>
        <script src="ol3-layerswitcher.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map" style="width:100%;"></div>
    <div id="info"></div>
    <script src="javascript3.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```